# Find object value in array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if a object value exist in a array of objects with "some".

I only can find that the object hobbys exist in the array with "some"

```
"users": [
   {
     "type": "User",
     "name": "Sarah",
     "hobbys":
      {
        first: "something1",
        second: "something2"
      }
   }
]

users.some(item => item.hobbys); // true
```

I want to check if "first" value in "hobbys" exist.

Comment: It's 'hobbies', just in case

Comment: `users.some(user => user.hobbies.first);`

Comment: @DennisVash That will throw if `user.hobbies` does not exist

Comment: @CertainPerformance users.some(user => user.hobbies && user.hobbies.first); ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `hobbys` is an object and has an own property of `first`:

```js
const users = [{
  "type": "User",
  "name": "Sarah",
  "hobbys": {
    first: "something1",
    second: "something2"
  }
}];

const userWithFirstHobbyExists = users.some(({ hobbys }) => (
 typeof hobbys === 'object' && hobbys.hasOwnProperty('first')
));
console.log(userWithFirstHobbyExists);
```

Comment: To me `hasOwnProperty()` is a tool for tracking down the inheritance, which is muuuuch slower than simple `users.some(item => item.hobbys.first != undefined || false)`. What's the benefit of using `hasOwnProperty()` here?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is the way to check to see if the property exists on the object: `!= undefined` will also evaluate to `false` if the property does exist, but its value is `undefined`. It's an edge case, but from OP's question, it's not clear if it's something to worry about or not. If he also wants to exclude `first` values of `undefined`, then you're right, check `!== undefined`

Comment: The question body states *"want to check if "first" value in "hobbys" **exist**"*, so regardless of the `first` value, `hasOwnProperty()` seems to be massive overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following assuming `hobbys` will always be an `object` and `first` will not have any **falsy** values.

```js
let users = [{"type": "User","name": "Sarah","hobbys": {"first": "something1","second": "something2"}}];

console.log(users.some(item => item.hobbys && item.hobbys.first)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"key" in obj` also to check if a key is part if object.

```js
const users = [{
  "type": "User",
  "name": "Sarah",
  "hobbys": {
    first: "something1",
    second: "something2"
  }
}];

const userWithFirstHobbyExists = users.some(({ hobbys }) => (
 typeof hobbys === 'object' && ('first' in hobbys )
));
console.log(userWithFirstHobbyExists);
```

Alternate and fast way to check is

```js
    const users = [{
      "type": "User",
      "name": "Sarah",
      "hobbys": {
        first: "something1",
        second: "something2"
      }
    }];

    const userWithFirstHobbyExists = users.some(({ hobbys }) => (
     typeof hobbys === 'object' && hobbys['first'] !== undefined
    ));
    console.log(userWithFirstHobbyExists);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = [{
  "type": "User",
  "name": "Sarah",
  "hobbys": {
    first: "somethig1",
    second: "something2"
  }
}];

const hobbyExists = users.some(({ hobbys }) => (typeof hobbys === 'object' && hobbys['first']));
console.log(hobbyExists);
```

Answer (score 0):

function will return true if it has value else false

```js
let jData = {
    "users": [{
        "type": "User",
        "name": "Sarah",
        "hobbys": {
            "first": "something1",
            "second": "something2"
        }
    }]
};

function hasValue(data, obj, key) {
    return data.some(item => item[obj] && item[obj][key]);
}
console.log(hasValue(jData.users, 'hobbys', 'second')) //true
console.log(hasValue(jData.users, 'hobbys', 'first')) // true
console.log(hasValue(jData.users, 'test', 'first'))  //false
```